# Backend process

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a client and we have developed around 10 Asp.net sites for him. Each sites has their own way of order creation. I want to have a generic approach which processes the orders placed  in each site. At present I am looping all the sites and checking whether there is any order waiting to be processed (in a console application). This doesn't seem to be a valid approach.

Like, one site has around 1000 orders waiting to be processed and my job will wait until it is done with them and orders from rest of the sites will wait.

I thought of following things

1. Keep each request in a separate thread and limiting
2. Use SQL Server agent to call web services??

Is there any suggestion to implement it in a better way?

My sites are developed using Asp.Net web forms, c#.net and SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 3):

```
   "Async" in a very eaaaaaaaaaaaaasy way, by using my way: Async.cs

    Usage>

    /* ___________________ Summary ___________________ */
    Async.GetDataAsync<List<double>>(GetSomeDoubles, DoubleArrived);// DoubleArrived takes List<double> as param

    Async.DoAsync(doSomethingIns, doNextthingIns); // both are voids


    /* ___________________ Details ___________________ */

    /* ========= GetAsync ========= */
    Async.GetDataAsync<List<int>>(
    () =>
    {
      //Code as you like
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
      return Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
    },
    (List<int> data) =>
    {
      MessageBox.Show(data.Count.ToString());
    });

    /* ========= GetAsync ========= */ 
    Async.GetDataAsync<object>(
    () =>
    {
      //Code as you like
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
      return 5;
    },
    delegate (object data)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());
    });

    /* ======== Do some thing Async ======== */
    Async.DoAsync(
    () =>
    {
      //Code as you like
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    },
    () =>
    {
      MessageBox.Show("You did it async :)");
    });

    /* ======== Do some thing Async ======== */
    Async.DoAsync(
    () =>
    {
      //Code as you like
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    },
    delegate()
    {
      MessageBox.Show("You did it async again :)");
    });
```

The Async class : Async.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

public class Async
{
    public class DataByThreadWorker<T>
    {
        private BackgroundWorker bw = null;

        public delegate T GetDataDelegate();
        public GetDataDelegate getDataIns;

        public delegate void CallCompleted(T data);
        public CallCompleted dataCompletedIns;

        public delegate void DoSomething();
        public DoSomething doSomethingIns;
        public DoSomething doNexthingIns;

        public void DoAsync()
        {
            if (doSomethingIns != null)
            {
                bw = new BackgroundWorker();
                bw.DoWork += bw_DoWorkVoid;
                bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerVoidCompleted;
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Ooops, doSomethingIns should not be null !!!");
            }
        }

        public void GetDataAsync()
        {
            if (getDataIns != null)
            {
                bw = new BackgroundWorker();
                bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
                bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Ooops, getDataIns should not be null !!!");
            }
        }

        /*===========================================================================*/

        void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (getDataIns != null) e.Result = getDataIns();
        }

        void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataCompletedIns != null) dataCompletedIns((T)e.Result);
        }

        /*===========================================================================*/

        void bw_DoWorkVoid(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (doSomethingIns != null) doSomethingIns(); 
            e.Result = true;
        }

        void bw_RunWorkerVoidCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (doNexthingIns != null) doNexthingIns();
        }
    }

    /*======================================================================================================================================================*/

    public static void GetDataAsync<T>(DataByThreadWorker<T>.GetDataDelegate GetDataFunc, DataByThreadWorker<T>.CallCompleted DataCompletedDelegate)
    {
        DataByThreadWorker<T> dt = new DataByThreadWorker<T>();
        dt.getDataIns = GetDataFunc;
        dt.dataCompletedIns = DataCompletedDelegate;
        dt.GetDataAsync();
    }

    public static void DoAsync(DataByThreadWorker<object>.DoSomething doSomethingIns, DataByThreadWorker<object>.DoSomething doNextthingIns)
    {
        DataByThreadWorker<object> dt = new DataByThreadWorker<object>();
        dt.doSomethingIns = doSomethingIns;
        dt.doNexthingIns = doNextthingIns;
        dt.DoAsync();
    }

}
```